# Using StorageFile class having the file content in UWP [Universal Windows Platform]

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, uwp

I have an API service which converts files and sends back a converted PDF file, in fact it's content, using a standard `HttpClient` with POST method. I do not need a physical copy of the file on my disk, but its equivalent as a `StorageFile` class.

I have some questions regarding this topic to which I couldn't find answers anywhere:

1. How to create a file when I get the content of it using the `StorageFile` class? Or do I need to use another class to initially create a file (e.g. File)? Is it recommended in UWP?
2. Is there a way to use the `StorageFile` class without creating a physical copy of a file?
3. What option is better - first save the file in a temp folder and then use it or directly create a `StorageFile` class? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to create a file when I get the content of it using the StorageFile class? Or do I need to use another class to initially create a file (e.g. File)? Is it recommended in UWP?

The content received are commonly string format. You may need to create a new blank file in some place, frequently is the local folder of the current app. Then, write the content to the file you just created. Here is a very sample demo:

```
string content = "postcontent";
StorageFolder localfolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.pdf", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, content);
```

Details for how to create and write a file with `StorageFile` please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). Pay attention that this is just a simple creating and writing file sample, for real pdf file, this need complex formats content writing to the file.

[`StorageFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) class is for file operation in uwp, we use this class create and write files, other classes are may not be needed. [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class which belong `System.IO` name space should be also used in uwp, but `StorageFile` is recommended.

> Is there a way to use the StorageFile class without creating a physical copy of a file

I'm afraid not. As I said above `StorageFile` is for accessing a file object, if there is no file how to access? The content you received should not be a file object, they may be text or file stream.

> What option is better - first save the file in a temp folder and then use it or directly create a StorageFile class? Why?

Create a temp file and you will have a `StorageFile` instance and then you should be able to write the received content of file stream by the `StorageFile` object. It seems like create a temp file in a local folder is the better way since `StorageFile` may not be created by http content.

Furthermore, file access in UWP has special permission we may need to pay attention, details you can reference [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the `StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.createstreamedfileasync.aspx) to create a virtual `StorageFile`. You give it a name, a delegate, and an optional thumbnail. When somebody tries to access the contents of the virtual `StorageFile`, your delegate will be invoked, and its job is to fill the provided output stream with data.

Sketch:

```
private async Task<StorageFile> ConvertFileAsync(StorageFile originalFile)
{
    var resultBuffer = await PostFileToServiceAndGetResultAsync(originalFile);

    return
        await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync("result.pdf",
            async (request) => {
                using (request)
                {
                    await request.WriteAsync(resultBuffer);
                }
            }, null);
}
```

Another example can be found [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streamedfiledatarequestedhandler.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Saving it to temporary storage is probably the easiest, but you could also just implement IStorageFile yourself and keep your downloaded pdf in memory as a variable in the new class.